# belkin modem cum router setup on Ubuntu 12.10 with BSNL broadband

Tags: modem, router

I have bsnl broadband and I am using belkin f9j1001v1 belkin modem-router. The setup cd that comes with Belkin only supports Windows and Mac. How do I get drivers of it for Ubuntu so that I can setup the router and eventually configure it for WiFi accessibility?

I tried accessing  and configure. The dhcp was detected but internet is never detected.

please help if anyone has encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drivers are never needed for a Router. A router will always be accessed via a web page. You can determine the web page to go to by looking at your IP settings.

So if you execute the command `ifconfig` you get an output like

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:36:50:55  
          inet addr:192.168.1.144  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe36:5055/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:95235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68090 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:124193612 (124.1 MB)  TX bytes:6263115 (6.2 MB)
```

This tells me web address is very likely to be at `http://192.168.1.1` which is the lowest address for your segment.

As to internet not working first connect without router to see it works, which it probably does. then plug the cable into the WAN port and your computer into the LAN port on the back

Answer (score 1):

Open a web browser and type in the IP address 192.168.2.1 of the modem-router written on the underside of it.You would  then  see the login page of modem-router.Click on submit.Then click on lan settings.Enable dhcp.Then click on apply changes.Then click on connection type,  click on PPoE,click on next.Type the username and password,select 'Yes'for IP assigned by ISP.Type 0 for vpi and 35 for vci.Select LLC for Encapsulation.Click on apply changes.Your internet connection has been set up.